# Rails really weird issue starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I just initiated a new rails app with Rails new, changed the default database settings into PostgresSQL. I start the server with bin/rails s and I get this weird

```
2016-04-21 05:00:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-04-21 05:00:33] INFO  ruby 2.1.3 (2014-09-19) [i686-linux]
[2016-04-21 05:00:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12160 port=3000


Started GET "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LGtCFqz" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-04-21 05:00:38 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/socket.io"):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) 

lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

This line in the stack trace really concerns me:

```
Started GET "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LGtCFqz" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-04-21 05:00:38 +0000
```

I had a websocket gem installed called em-websockets as well as the thin gem. I uninstalled both from Ruby but I still get this error.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# postgres db
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

This is my gemfile. It has nothing with websockets as far as I can tell. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some kind of [Socket.io](http://socket.io) code running on your front-end? Does another app on your computer which might access the same port?

Comment: it might be that I was playing around with meteor before and meteor doesn't kill the ports?

Comment: If you still have a Meteor page open somewhere it's probably poking your Rails server thinking it can connect again. This is why I like using [Pow](http://pow.cx), it makes each app separate.

Comment: Does `ps aux | grep socket` bring up anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted and restarted the server in default rails(0.0.0.0:3000).
It fixed itself.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5):

For Anyone who is really interested to know what is really happening here.

This is not a Rails application issue.

Rails is running on port http://localhost:3000 by default.

Like Rails App, you may have another server (Ex: `Gulp / NodeJS`) run on the same port 3000. This server has been stopped and you started Rails server on the port 3000 instead.

Now the funny part coming into play. One of your old server's client is still requesting to your old `Gulp / NodeJS` server, assuming that it is still on port 3000 ( but it is hitting `Rails` on port 3000 :) ).

Actually the client is requesting to `Gulp / NodeJS` server, in that port you have Rails app running.

`socket.io` is a realtime application that work well with NodeJS.

That is why you see these weird `GET` requests in your Rails logs.

```
GET "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LGtCFqz" => this is not supposed to come into Rails application
```

And you blame Rails application and think why this error is happening !!

[image: Rails Logger]

What you can do is just make sure that all the browser tabs apart from Rails app, that connecting to 3000 is closed.